# Generate Unique Code/ID In Contact form ? PHP/Ajax

Tags: php, contact-form, ajaxform

Hello So I have my contact form and everything is working fine What I want to do now is have the PHP Generate a unique code/id for example "002302103" and attach it to the email when the email is submitted. 
Basically a random reference number that is generated each time the form is used and that random set of numbers is also sent with the email.
Does anyone know how I go about this ?

Here is my php code:

```
    <?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_Email       = "MyEmail@Email.com"; 
    $subject        = 'Message from my website'; //Subject line for emails


    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        //exit script outputting json data
        $output = json_encode(
        array(
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Request must come from Ajax'
        ));

        die($output);
    } 

    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["userName"]) || !isset($_POST["userEmail"]) || !isset($_POST["userMessage"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Input fields are empty!'));
        die($output);
    }

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_Name        = filter_var($_POST["userName"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_Email       = filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $user_Message     = filter_var($_POST["userMessage"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $user_Message = str_replace("\&#39;", "'", $user_Message);
    $user_Message = str_replace("&#39;", "'", $user_Message);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_Name)<4) // If length is less than 4 it will throw an HTTP error.
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //email validation
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($user_Message)<5) //check emtpy message
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_Email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $user_Message . "\r\n\n"  .'-- '.$user_Name. "\r\n" .'-- '.$user_Email, $headers);

    if(!$sentMail)
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_Name .'! Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for helping/pointing me in the right direction

Comment: You want some kind of validation with unique code/id or its just a kind of reference number?

Comment: You can use timestamp. Still depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Just a reference number so to speak just random numbers that are different each time the form is used

Comment: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Comment: You can use timestamp numbers or some random number generation function for that. Or append time stamp with some random numbers to make it totally unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
echo mt_rand() . "\n";
echo mt_rand() . "\n";
```

Its output is:

```
1604716014
1478613278
```

[mt_rand() Reference:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

Append this to your message like:

```
$subject = 'Message from my website - '.$mt_rand();
```

Comment: Works perfectly how could I get this to display in the subject line? $subject        = 'Message from my website'; I've played with it but it breaks the form any ideas?

Comment: This is what I tried originally it seems to break the form oddly

Comment: It was $subject = 'Message from my website - '.mt_rand(); Thank you for your help marking as correct

Comment: Enjoy the coding :P

Answer (score 1):

Using `time()` as mentioned will give you a sortable way to create unique IDs. Concatenating strings will also further randomize your desired result and still keep it sortable:

```
$uniqueId= time().mt_rand();
```